# Python: reduce lightness of a RGB color

Tags: python, colors, rgb, hsl

Is there a simple way to change the lightness of a color given as RGB string?

E.g.

```
in_RGB = '#FF0000'  --> out_RGB = '#CC0000'
```

Comment: Convert the RGB to HSV and decrease V?

Comment: Yes, I just wondered if there was a compact way to do that (or some best practice)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not that hard to convert a hex string to an RGB 3-tuple.

Once you've done that, you can use the [`colorsys`](http://docs.python.org/library/colorsys.html#module-colorsys) module (or if you prefer to implement it yourself, the equations [here](http://www.easyrgb.com/index.php?X=MATH)) to convert from RGB to HSL, then do the manipulation you want, and then convert back from HSL to RGB.

Then just convert back to hex, add the `#` sign again, and you're good to go.

Comment: Thanks. To make it simpler I actually did it by dividing each RGB component for the same ratio and then obtain the string back.

Comment: I converted the string using 3 statements: `R = int(str_hex[0:2], 16); G = int(str_hex[2:4], 16); B = int(str_hex[4:6], 16);`. Is there a more straightforward way?

Comment: `r,g,b = (int(str_hex[2x:2x+2]) for x in xrange(3))` is an option, albeit not much more straightforward.